# How to create a list of indices from a 2D list?

Tags: python, list

If I have a 2 dimensional list, how can I generate a list of indices for a specific element in that 2D list?

For example, if I have the list

```
two_d_list = [[0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

How could I make a list with this format

```
index_list = [[0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 3]]
```

which is the list of 2 dimensional indexes of all 1s in `two_d_list`.
The format of

```
index_list = [(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 3)]
```

would also work. I just need to retrieve the indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With list comprehension:

```
>>> [(r, c) for r, line in enumerate(two_d_list) for c, num in enumerate(line) if num==1]

[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
two_d_list = [[0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]

result = []
for i in range(len(two_d_list)):
    for j in range(len(two_d_list[i])):
        if two_d_list[i][j] == 1:
            result.append((i, j))

print(result)
```

Result:

```
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with list of lists can be cumbersome and quite slow. If you are able to use `numpy` arrays in your application, the solution becomes quite easy and fast.

```py
import numpy as np
two_d_list = [[0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
# Create a numpy array
arr = np.array(two_d_list)
    
# np.where implements exactly the functionality you are after 
# then you stack the two lists of indices and transpose
indices = np.stack(np.where(arr == 1)).T
print(indices)
```